# NodeMCU - Lua and si7021

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

Was anyone able to use si7021 with a Lua script on an ESP8266 board?

http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/si7021/#si7021setup

I'm getting always exception:

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x40100000, len 27228, room 16  
tail 12  
chksum 0x76  
ho 0 tail 12 room 4  
load 0x3ffe8000, len 2184, room 12  
tail 12  
chksum 0xc2  
ho 0 tail 12 room 4  
load 0x3ffe8888, len 136, room 12  
tail 12  
chksum 0x16  
csum 0x16
```

This is the piece of code I'm using:

```
function initSTH()
    print("init i2c")
    i2c.setup(0, 5, 6, i2c.SLOW) -- call i2c.setup() only once

    print("init si7021")
    si7021.setup()

    print("configuring it")
    res, vdds, heater, heater_set = si7021.setting(si7021.RH12_TEMP14)

    print("res: " .. res .. "vdds: " .. vdds .. "heater: " .. heater .. "heater_set: " .. heater_set )
end
```

Comment: What if you introduce a delay between `si7021.setup()` and `si7021.setting()` using `tmr.create():alarm()`?

Comment: Thanks, i've tried already.   Same error.